# How to Explain this C Union Output

Tags: c, unions

```
#include <stdio.h>
union p
{
    int x;
    char y;
}
k = {.y = 97};

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", k.y);
    return 0;
}

OUTPUT: 97
```

I came across this Question. As we know we can only initialize the first member of Union. But in this, at the time of initialization, the `y` variable is initialized through some given method!

Can anyone explain this to me how **k={ .Y=97}** is breaking the rule stated in Dennis Ritchie's book "Union can only be initialized with a value of the type of its first member" and initializing the second variable instead ?

Comment: Who told you you can only initialize the first member of some `union`? This is a mistake (you can initialize any single member of some union).

Comment: The designated initialisers were introduced in c99. dmr did not know about that back in the seventies.

Comment: Maybe endianness reversed the rule.

Comment: +1 Good Question. I didn't know this too !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

K&R is a great book, but it is old. In C99 You can do this.

> Using a designated initializer in the same example, the following
>   initializes the second union member age :

```
union {
       char birthday[9];
       int age;
       float weight;
      } people = { .age = 14 };
```

Comment: You say "K&R ... is old". I tend to think, in the computer world, 35 years (1st edition was 1978) is somewhat beyond "old"... Even the 2nd edition, which IIRC was 1988, is "old"...